# Ansible Playbook passing array list as variable

Tags: ansible

so we currently have a create directories yml and it has 20 or so folders it creates..  I'm attempting to streamline that and pass in the folders with the mode and recurse flag which are all different.  As a test I created this.

```
- debug: msg="testing = {{ testing }}"
- name: "loop through list from a variable"
  debug:
    msg: "dest: {{ item.dest }}, mode: {{ item.mode }}, recurse: {{ item.recurse }}"
  with_items: "{{ testing }}"
```

Normally we have something like this:

```
- name: Create Multiple Directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item.dest }}"
    mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
    recurse: "{{ item.recurse }}"
    state: directory
  with_items:
    - { dest: '/local/path1', mode: '0775', recurse: yes }
    - { dest: '/local/path2', mode: '0777', recurse: no }
```

So my problem is we use AaaS to pass information over and how the parameter is set.. We have a TextBox on a web page.   I tried the following with no luck.

```
- { dest: '/local/path1', mode: '0775', recurse: yes }
- { dest: '/local/path2', mode: '0777', recurse: no }
```

and

```
{ dest: '/local/path1', mode: '0775', recurse: yes }
{ dest: '/local/path2', mode: '0777', recurse: no }
```

and

```
dest: '/local/path1', mode: '0775', recurse: yes
dest: '/local/path2', mode: '0777', recurse: no
```

The error I'm getting in all cases states 'dest' does not exist.   Is it formatting or is there something else I need to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have rep to make a comment, but i would think that the yaml you're sending in the first example is a list, but sending yaml via HTTP to an AaaS is difficult. You might try sending a JSON blob, so you can send:

```
[{"dest": "/local/path1", "mode": "0775", "recurse": true },
{"dest": "/local/path2", "mode": "0777", "recurse": false }]
```

And that would probably make your life easier

EDIT: removed the single quotes as it's likely that a Text Box would be interpreted as a string already

Comment: Whoops, I thought I was on ServerFault still. This is the one site I do have the ability to make a comment. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: no worries.. worth the try..  Also tried it with ` instead of ' and still same error.

Comment: What's the error? Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also it would be worth noting what the AaaS actually is. If it's AWX or Ansible Tower it might help frame the issue. Maybe add a tag for that too, this honestly really isn't an issue with the Ansible per se

Comment: @Switch you tried backticks on the JSON blob? Did you try it without the single quotes entirely? It would make sense that a text box is interpreted as a string anyways without the need for the single quotes

Comment: This worked!!   ok: [serverdomain.com] => (item={'dest': '/local/path1', 'recurse': True, 'mode': '0775'}) => {
    "item": {
        "dest": "/local/path1", 
        "mode": "0775", 
        "recurse": true
    }, 
    "msg": "dest: /local/path1, mode: 0775, recurse: True"
}
ok: [serverdomain.com] => (item={'dest': u'/local/path2', 'recurse': False, 'mode': u'0777'}) => {
    "item": {
        "dest": "/local/path2", 
        "mode": "0777", 
        "recurse": false
    }, 
    "msg": "dest: /local/path2, mode: 0777, recurse: False"
}

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Is it formatting or is there something else I need to consider?"*

A: The code works for me. (I've only changed the destinations e.g. `dest: '/usr/local/test/path1'`). See below the dir before and after.

```sh
shell> tree /usr/local/test
/usr/local/test

0 directories, 0 files

shell> tree /usr/local/test
/usr/local/test
├── path1
└── path2

2 directories, 0 files

shell> ll /usr/local/test
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jun  1 21:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Jun  1 21:00 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  1 21:00 path1/
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Jun  1 21:00 path2/
```

---

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Create Multiple Directories
      file:
        path: "{{ item.dest }}"
        mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
        recurse: "{{ item.recurse }}"
        state: directory
      with_items:
        - {dest: '/usr/local/test/path1', mode: '0775', recurse: yes}
        - {dest: '/usr/local/test/path2', mode: '0777', recurse: no}
```

Comment: Which one did you use?   I show 3 different things passed in.

Comment: The 1st one. `with_items` requires a list.

Comment: The first one works, because we have no variables going through it.  That is what we have today.   I'm trying to get the ones with a variable array.